# Model paper clips validations errors are not displayed in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, paperclip, jruby, simple-form

I am using paper_clip and simple_form gems. Unfortunately, it seems that paper clip validations errors are not displayed in my form.

I have try several types and syntax of paper_clip content_type validations and even they work (the uploaded files types are restricted) no error is displayed in the form.

Has anyone knew know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I suspect - the paperclip validation is likely being made on an attribute that's not actually an input in simple_form.

You might have something like this in your form:

```
<%= f.input :picture, :label => "Picture" %>
```

But paperclip's validation errors aren't going to be put on 'picture' - they'll be put on another attribute, like 'picture_file_name'. Since simple_form has a 'picture' input, and not a 'picture_file_name' input, it doesn't know where to put the errors, so they don't show up.

Take a look at your errors array and confirm what attribute's getting the errors. Then use simple_form's errors helper in your view to put that attribute's error in the appropriate place:

```
<%= f.error :picture_file_name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately paperclip provides own format for validation errors storing them in 3 different attributes without linking to base model attribute:

*_file_name, *_file_size, *_content_type

Therefore simple_form or any other form view helper could not map paperclip validation errors with field name.

You can patch paperclip like described here http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/05/paperclip-bootstrap-and-simpleform-working-together-on-rails/ and forget about this issue forever